# Retrieve URL that has password

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am retrieving data via NSURLRequest and it is working perfectly. I have added password protection to that directory now and I am not sure how to configure my code to add in the password for the directory (myStuff)

Can anyone tell me how this is done based on my current code?

Thank you

```
 -(void) retrieve
 {
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXXXXXX.com/myStuff/test.php"]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:8.0];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

  if (theConnection) {
  receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
  } else {
  // Inform the user that the connection failed.
  [self showServerAlert];
  return;
 }
}


  //CALL THE OTHER DELEGATE METHODS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard URL syntax would be:

```
http://username:password@XXXXX.com/myStuff/test.php
```

When doing this though you should not use `http`. You really want to use `https`. And don't hardcode the password in your code. A hacker could easily figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean? What password directory?

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I tried to make that change but the application crashes on me when I put that code in. And yes I did replace username and password with the correct values. Do you have any other suggestions or know why it is crashing?

Comment: Also, for https, does my website not have to contain a security certificate in other for it work? Currently my site does not contain such a certificate. Thanks!

Comment: Without details about the error, there is no way to help. And yes, to use https your web server needs to be setup properly.

Comment: Okay just to verify, if my username was ted and my password was abc, the code would look like http://ted:abc@XXXXX.com/myStuff/test.php

Comment: Sure, try in your web browser to be sure.

Comment: Okay so it works perfect in the browser but in the application, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Without the username:password, it runs fine (does not get the data but does not crash). Thanks again for all your help thus far

Comment: You need to update your question with more details about the crash. Include detail about the stack trace from where it crashed. Most likely the crash is in other code since you are now getting further.

Comment: It was a crash on my part. My apologies. Final question and I will let you be :) You say it is bad practise to hardcode the username and password. How then would you suggest going about it then? Thank you, will accept!

Comment: That's a whole other discussion. Do some searching on that subject. It can't be answered in a simple comment.